# Unable to click the TextView inside the listView

Tags: android

My code is to list out all personal details of employees, and once we click on the phone number, it will be able to dial the number.
But, how to solve the unclickable TextView in the ListView?
I need to click twice in order to dial the number.. seeking for help thanks

## MainActivity

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
                    adapter = new AgentAdapter(this, arrayList);
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            
                    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                            final SalesAgent agent = arrayList.get(position);
            
                            TextView phone_field = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.phone);
                            phone_field.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                                    intent.setData(Uri.parse(agent.getPhone()));
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
```

## Customized ArrayAdapter

```
            public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
                    View listItemView = convertView;
                    if(listItemView == null){
                        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
                    }
            
                    //change background colours
                    listItemView.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorSkyBlue));
            
                    currentAgent = getItem(position);
            
                    TextView name_field = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
                    TextView website_field = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.website);
                    final TextView phone_field = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.phone);
            
                    name_field.setText(currentAgent.getName());
                    website_field.setText(currentAgent.getWebsite());
                    phone_field.setText(currentAgent.getPhone());
            
                    return listItemView;
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set TextView#OnClickListener inside Adapter#getView and not inside ListView#OnItemClickListener

Like this:

```
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
                View listItemView = convertView;
                if(listItemView == null){
                    listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
                }

                //change background colours
                listItemView.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorSkyBlue));

                currentAgent = getItem(position);

                TextView name_field = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
                TextView website_field = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.website);
                final TextView phone_field = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.phone);

                name_field.setText(currentAgent.getName());
                website_field.setText(currentAgent.getWebsite());
                phone_field.setText(currentAgent.getPhone());
                phone_field.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                                intent.setData(Uri.parse(agent.getPhone()));
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        });
                return listItemView;
            }
```

EDIT

you should add into your constructor adapter your activity instance for use startActivity method, so assuming "myActivity" is your variabile should be like this

```
myActivity.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I added getContext().startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {

        holder = new ViewHolder();

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout. list_item, null);

        holder.name_field = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.website_field = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.website);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    final CurrentAgent currentAgent = getItem(position);

    holder.name_field.setText(currentAgent.getName());

    holder.name_field.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           // DO WHATEVER YOU WANT
        }
    });
return convertView;
}

public class ViewHolder {

       TextView name_field;
       TextView website_field;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to perform simple click operation by:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        final SalesAgent agent = arrayList.get(position);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(agent.getPhone()));
        startActivity(intent);
        }
     });
}
```

You don't need again to use `click listener` of `TextView`. The position of item in `ListView` can be retrieved from `position` parameter in `onItemClick` method.

Comment: By using this way, is it we only selecting the ListView item and not the TextView of phone number?

Comment: You will retrieve everything of that item in the list.

Comment: Actually there is a link to issue an intent to a web, so if using the way that you have suggested, may be it is not so advisable?

Answer (score 0):

As a recommendation, it is better to use recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

You must add a listener in your adapter, I hope and sriva my example, Regards.

```
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
                    View listItemView = convertView;
                    if(listItemView == null){
                        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
                    }

                    //change background colours
                    listItemView.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorSkyBlue));

                    currentAgent = getItem(position);

                    TextView name_field = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
                    TextView website_field = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.website);
                    final TextView phone_field = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.phone);
                    //here add listener texview
                    phone_field.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onClick(View v) {
                          // your code call phone 
                      }
                    });

                    name_field.setText(currentAgent.getName());
                    website_field.setText(currentAgent.getWebsite());
                    phone_field.setText(currentAgent.getPhone());

                    return listItemView;
                }
```